# Perl utf8 not quite working with my script

Tags: perl, utf-8, html-email

I'm having a problem with utf-8 support on a perl script I'm writing. The script is meant to send html email messages. The html messages are saved in UTF-8 format inside a PostgreSQL database. Everything seems to be working but still I get corruption sometimes when I receive an email from the script - "�".

In the beginning of the script I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use utf8;
use Encode;
use MIME::Base64;
use MIME::Lite;  

my $connection = DBI->connect('dbi:Pg:dbname='.$db_name.';host='.$db_host.'', $db_user,$db_pass, { AutoCommit=>1, PrintError => 1, pg_enable_utf8 => 1 });

my $fetchHtml = $connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM emails ORDER BY n_id DESC LIMIT 1');
$fetchHtml->execute();

my $message = $fetchHtml->fetchrow_hashref();

my $sendMsg = MIME::Lite->build(
    Encoding    => 'quoted-printable',
    Type        => 'multipart',
    To          => '<atesting@address.com>',
    From        => '<destination@address.com>',
    Subject     => encode("MIME-B", $message->{'title'}),
    Data        => decode_entities($message->{'html'})
);

$sendMsg->attr("Content-Type" => "text/html; charset=utf-8;");

$sendMsg->send_by_smtp('127.0.0.1', Timeout =>30, Debug => 0, SkipBad => 1);
```

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong and why do I keep on getting the cool "�" sign ? :)

Another thing is that I get this exception when I execute the script:

```
Uncaught exception from user code:
    Wide character in subroutine entry at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/MIME/Lite.pm line 2259.
at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/MIME/Lite.pm line 2259
    MIME::Lite::print_simple_body('MIME::Lite=HASH(0xa51b9c8)', 'MIME::Lite::SMTP=GLOB(0xa5b8888)', 1) called at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/MIME/Lite.pm line 2191
    MIME::Lite::print_body('MIME::Lite=HASH(0xa51b9c8)', 'MIME::Lite::SMTP=GLOB(0xa5b8888)', 1) called at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/MIME/Lite.pm line 2126
    MIME::Lite::print_for_smtp('MIME::Lite=HASH(0xa51b9c8)', 'MIME::Lite::SMTP=GLOB(0xa5b8888)') called at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/MIME/Lite.pm line 2897
    MIME::Lite::send_by_smtp('MIME::Lite=HASH(0xa51b9c8)', 'bla.example.com', 'Timeout', 30, 'Debug', 0, 'SkipBad', 1) called at ./advanced-daemon.pl line 354
    main::send_mail('Subject Title' <webmaster@testing>', 'spam@spam.com', 'HASH(0xa518630)') called at ./advanced-daemon.pl line 225
    main::sendEmailsToSubscribers('DBI::db=HASH(0xa517f40)', 24, 'HASH(0xa518630)') called at ./advanced-daemon.pl line 136
```

I can't understand what exactly is the problem but I think it's related to the utf8..
Any help would be pretty much appreciated.. :)

Comment: Could you be more specific? Do you get just this sign or this amongst others correctly formated characters? Do you have any idea which characer it should be?

Comment: No I don't have a clue what character it should be. The html is generated via php and it's random. I'm sure that the data inserted in the database is utf8 encoded. Why does this sign display - I can't tell... I doesn't display when I print out the html via php..
The more interesting thing is that exception which comes out once every now and then. How can I investigate why it's throwing and exception?

Answer (score 1):

First you need `use utf8` only if you have unicode character in the quellcode. Then `decode_entities($message->{'html'})` ist also wrong. Use only `$message->{'html'}`.
The database must be utf8 by default. Then add `Encoding    => '8bit'`. That works nice for me.

Your MIME::Lite is false: see on http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=105262 for a nice example

Answer (score 0):

In my code I use the `multipart` type and here is the version which seems to work correctly.

```perl
my $mail_htm = 'Text of the email with utf8 characters like these: ľščťžýáíúäô';
my $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
    From      =>'me@me.com',
    'Reply-To'=>'me@me.com',
    To        =>'you@you.com',
    Subject   => 'Simple ascii non-utf8 subject',
    Type      =>'multipart/mixed'
);
my $msg_body = MIME::Lite->new(
    Type    =>'multipart/alternative'
);
$msg_body->attach(
    Type    =>'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
    Encoding=>'quoted-printable',
    Data    =>$mail_htm
);
$msg->attach($msg_body);
```

I didn't play much with utf8 encoding for the subject as I didn't need it that much and several solutions I found around didn't work.